# Failed to install libxml-ruby 2.3.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, libxml2

I'm trying to install [Team Dashboard](https://github.com/fdietz/team_dashboard)  on Ruby on Rails and getting errors when installing libxml-ruby

From a few posts of Stackoverflow I see a lot of poeple mention installing libxslt-dev and libxml2-dev which I've done but the problem persists.

I'm running:

```
  gem install libxml-ruby -v '2.3.3'
```

OS: openSUSE 12.3 (i586)

libxslt-devel-1.1.28-3.4.1.i586

libxslt1-1.1.28-3.4.1.i586

libxml2-2-2.9.0-2.17.1.i586

libxml2-devel-2.9.0-2.17.1.i586

gem: v2.0.3

ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [i686-linux]

The error is:

```
 Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
 ERROR:  Error installing libxml-ruby:
 ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
```

Any ideas - I'm stumped.

Here's the full error log:

http://pastebin.com/X5p5ey0r

Comment: do you install `libiconv` and `iconv` and `lsocket`? this packages are missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gave up and eventually install the latest version of libxml-ruby and it worked immediately.

```
 gem install libxml-ruby
```

Answer (score 1):

Please install

`libiconv` and `iconv` and `lsocket`? this packages are missing